# overflow-y no scroll bar

Tags: html, css, overflow, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal and the body of the modal is set to overflow-y: auto so that it scrolls the overflow:

```css
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fc4747;
}
.modal .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It does seem to scroll the overflow when I load it up with text, but it doesn't when I just have a tall div inside it. It just overflows. See image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bind="modal: showDialogue" style="display: block; padding-right: 15px;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 0px 25px; height: 140px;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row" style="">
          <div class="col-sm-4" style="">
            <div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/' + currentlySelectedProduct().product.imagePath + '\')' }" style="height: 160px; border-radius: 10px; color: white; vertical-align: bottom; background: url(&quot;../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/alpro_creamy_caramel.jpg&quot;) 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;">
            </div><!--image-->
          </div> <!--col-sm-6-->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div style="height: 110px; padding: 10px; background: #fc4747;">
              <h6 class="medium-text" data-bind="text: currentlySelectedProduct().product.brand" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: white; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:5px;">alpro</h6>
              <h6 class="medium-text" data-bind="text: currentlySelectedProduct().product.name" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: white; margin-bottom:5px;display: inline;">creamy caramel</h6>
            </div>
          </div> <!--col-sm-6-->
        </div> <!--row-->                   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does it overflow rather than scroll for tall divs?

** As a side note, I am setting the height of the bootstrap modal to be 80% of the window height (this needs to remain working):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-content').css('height',$( window ).height()*0.8);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `shown.bs.modal` and not `show.bs.modal`. If the code is in `show.bs.modal` event, modal's default code will overwrite your css related changes. If your changes are in `shown.bs.modal`, it guarantees that no more css changes will occurs from the modal's default code.

```
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   $('.modal-content').css('height', $(window).height() * 0.8);
 });
```

***show.bs.modal*** -   *Occurs when the modal is about to be shown*

***shown.bs.modal*** - *Occurs when the modal is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed)*

You might still have to play around with $(window).height() * 0.8. If the window height is very small, 80% of that will be much small. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Thanks. Doing that messes with my modal height. Sorry, I didn't specify what I was doing with my modal height. I have now added it to the bottom of the question.